# Biztalk Cumulative functoid Issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

We are mapping EDI 315 schema to a XML, and I have a requirement below.

```
Input EDI schema

N901="TN'' take N902

N901="TN1'' take N902

OutPut

Result= N902(N901="TN"),N902(N901="TN1")
```

That means in one ST & SE, I can have N901=TN & N901=TN1, these two values are mapped to a single field in destination schema. How can I do this?

I even tried mapping the two values to Cumulative functoid, but it's returning Null.

Answer (score 1):

To include a conditional statement when cumulatively concatenating a string you need to include the value mapping functoid.

Here is what the setup looks like:

[image: Example map setup]

The Equals functoids contain the comparisons which check the value of N901. The results are passed to an OR functoid which returns a single boolean value.

This boolean value is passed to the value mapping functoid along with the value of N902. When the boolean evaluates to true this functoid will pass the value of N902 to the cumulative concatenation functoid.